# How to deploy Angular 6 app on Azure using Visual Studio 2017

Tags: angular, azure, visual-studio-2017

I created an Angular app using angular-cli:

```
npm install -g @angular/cli

ng new my-app
```

Now I want to deploy this simple Angular app to Azure.

I have published setting how can I do it?

Comment: I wrote a very blog post regarding this https://medium.com/@omikolaj1/complete-guide-to-deploying-angular-and-asp-net-33a0976d0ec1

Answer (score 10, accepted):

After many hours of researching i found it and it is very simple

**just follow the steps**

1. run ng build --prod (this will create a dist folder in your application)
2. open visual studio and select **open** >> **website** select the path of your project inside dist folder and open
3. then just right click on your project and select **Publish Web App** then select your published profile setting and deploy it

Comment: Looking for some test site to upload in Azure. This is the quick and best one. Thanks a ton!

Comment: Yes, it is the better option.

Answer (score 2):

### VS Code

You can deploy your Angular App which is using **angular-cli** easily from Visual Studio Code(VS code)

Refer to this [article](https://dzone.com/articles/deploy-an-angular-app-from-visual-studio-code-to-a-1) (You just need to install the [Azure App Service extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-azuretools.vscode-azureappservice))

[image]

After you deployed the app,

[image]

### Visual Studio 2017

You need to create a Project as (ASP.NET Core Web application) as Angular Project

[image]

[image]

After then you can `publish` your App as WebPackage Deployment to Azure.

Here is the [Reference](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/build-angular-app-with-net-core-2-0-templatevs-2017-deploy-on-azure-step/) for Publishing your Angular App from VS 2017

**I'd say you can use the `Visual Studio Code` for your use-Case rather than `Visual Studio 2017`**

Comment: but i want to deploy cli app

Comment: @Faisal Use `Visual Studio Code` as i mentioned in my answer initially

Comment: @Faisal Refer the article in my answer which might useful

Comment: @Faisal Is my above answer helpful for you? If yes please accept/upvote my answer.

Comment: it was helpful for learning this side of technology but it did'nt work for me. i'll post my answer soon

Comment: That article in the link doesnt work. So many people who tried it could not get it work. No response from the author too.